# Extracting a method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, scope, extract, global, chain

I learned that if I wanted to extract a method from this example.

```
var jane={
name:'jane', 
describe:function(){
  return 'Person named '+this.name;
    }
};
```

I cannot do as follows.

```
var func =jane.describe;
func();
```

As it does not work, why does this not work? Also I was told the solution is as follows

```
var func =jane.describe.bind(jane);
func();
```

I do not understand this, what is this "bind" property of functions and why is "jane" passed into the bind property?

Answer (score 2):

This will not work because the context of `this` changes. When you use bind, you pass the object `jane` to `bind` so then when you call `describe` and it uses `this` it references `jane`.

As per the documentation:

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

**Reading Material**

[`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)